# Get the value of count in bash Linux

Tags: bash, html-parsing

I have below string like below

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>|| name: xzy || class: 9 || date: 07-01-2022 || marks:25</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to retrieve only marks I.e 25 . All the string values keeps changing. The name , date and marks are constant . I just want to get only marks value I.e 25
Please help

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, provide the code you've tried so far and the (wrong) output generated by your code; you may also want to look into using an html-aware tool for parsing html

Comment: Use a language with a HTML parser; `bash` is not such a language.

Comment: To get content of tag `h1` see: `xmlstarlet select --template --value-of "//html/body/h1" file.html`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -nE '/marks:[[:digit:]]+/s/^.*marks:([[:digit:]]+).*$/\1/p' path/to/file.html
```